# teammate overwrite committed code with outdated code

Tags: git, github

It happens when

1. my teammate re-indent/format the outdated code.
2. my teammate commited the file, Github didn't show any conflict.
3. my code got overwritten.

I am using Github Desktop (MACOS), hope it's clear.
I knew that -ignore-white-space might help, but I am not able to locate the diff option in Github Desktop.

Comment: Can you show the commands used and their output? We can't help without more information.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, my teammate using different code formatter. And
when he auto-format the code, git treat it as he updated the entire part and think my
teammate deletes the line as well. There might be some conflict when
he try to push, but he completely erase the current master branch
without checking (My new line). There's